# Play 1.2.5 application crashes on startup

Tags: java, playframework, nullpointerexception

after restarting the VPS I can't get Play application to run again. It was running before with no problems. I have been looking around and found no answer - it seems that nobody has encountered this before.

The stacktrace - https://gist.github.com/hojgr/79de9d1291b30de3a454d78013d92eec

It seems that there is a NullPointerException in Regex but that is out of scope of the application I am maintaining.

What could be wrong?

Thanks

Kind regards

Michal Hojgr

Comment: Looks like there's a NullPointerException in your press plugin. Check any references to press in the opening of your application. It may have cleared out a file from its cache that appears to be no longer necessary and yet it's still required. Something like that.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. We have fixed this issue by rolling back built frontend assets. There was some weird crash that has left the application in inconsistent state.